# Error when returning entity as JSON

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return an entity as JSON and I keep on getting this error:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Here is my code:

```
public JsonResult ListAllDepartments()
{
    JsonResult jsonResult = null;
    using (var db = new EventTrackerDB())
    {
        var foundDepartments = from departments in db.EVNTTRKR_Departments
                                   select departments;
        jsonResult = Json(foundDepartments.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return jsonResult;
}
```

I do not understand why the error is occurring.  I called toList() on the result set.

If I go to myapp/Departments/ListAllDepartments I get the error message.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: try `var foundDepartments = db.EVNTTRKR_Departments..ToList();                                   
             jsonResult = Json(foundDepartments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the `departments` object has some properties which are currently lazy-loaded.

If this is the case, you'll need to eager-load or explicitly load the objects.

More here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896249.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Everything is getting disposed when the using block end:

Try this:

```
public JsonResult ListAllDepartments()
{
   using (var db = new UsersContext())
   {
      var foundDepartments = from departments in db.EVNTTRKR_Departments
                             select departments;
      return Json(foundDepartments.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
 }
```

Hopes Its help you!